# Compute efficiently a 1D function relying on a 2D convolution

Tags: python, integral-equations, convolution

Let $X = [0,1]$,  $h$ the Gaussian function (i.e. $\forall x \in X, h(x) = e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$) and $p \in L^2(X^2)$

I would like to compute numerically the following function :

$$
\forall x \in X, \quad f(x) = \int_{X^2} p(s_1,s_2) h(s_1 - x) h(s_2 - x) \,\mathrm{d}(s_1,s_2)
$$

meaning that i have, a discretized grid for $X$, a matrix of all values of $p$ evaluated on (the grid of) $X^2$ and I would like to compute $f$ at every point of the grid. I already did:

- a numerical discretization of the integral
- a computation of the 2D convolution between the matrix $p$ and the outer product of $h$ (evaluated on the grid). Indeed in some sense $f(x) = (p \ast h \cdot h )(x,x)$ (it's just formal computation, excuse me for this kind of horror!) so taking the diagonal of the computed 2D convolution gives me the $f$ evaluated at the grid

My question is the following: **would you have an idea of the operation to be implemented in order not to calculate the whole convolution matrix but just its diagonal?** Would you have other ideas to calculate this function?

I specify that I code on Python and that I would like to be able to use the libraries already implemented, so if you have ideas that use SciPy functions it would be great!

Comment: Have you tried [`scipy.signal.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html)?

Comment: yes, i was more thinking about how to formulate the problem tbf. But I think I  got my answer

Comment: If you have your answer you can add it and even accept it. It might be useful to someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't manage to find a suitable formulation for the diagonal. But doing the convolution of the column then the convolution of the rows was enough computation time gain for me

```py
h_vec = gaussienne(X)
convol_row = scipy.signal.convolve(p, h_vec, 'same').T
adj = np.diag(scipy.signal.convolve(convol_row, h_vec, 'same'))
```